# Join two tables based on a criteria of string content in Table 1

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I have two tables which I'm joining by matching "some_name" of Table_A with "j_name" of Table_B. In few cases, I would like to join based on below criteria:

- if for example string "AB-FBb3" is found in Table_A, then I would like to match it against a specific value of "QT001" in Table_B.

Is this possbile?

```
Table_A:
**AB  some_name     G_NAME      Status        some_time**
------------------------------------------------------------
AAA    Job1        xxxxxxxxx   Ended OK    2020-06-29 10:37:52
AAA    AB-Jobd     xxxxxxxxx   Ended OK    2020-06-29 10:37:52
BBB    AB-ADu001   xxxxxxxxx   Ended OK    2020-06-29 10:37:52
BBB    AB-Job2     xxxxxxxxx   Ended OK    2020-06-29 10:37:52
BBB    AB-FBb3     xxxxxxxxx   Ended OK    2020-06-29 10:37:52

Table_B:
**RM  j_name           desc            rand_time**
----------------------------------------------------
111   AB-Job2         Sometext    2020-06-29 06:30:51
111   AB-Job5         Sometext1   2020-06-29 09:31:52
222   LLu001          Sometext2   2020-06-29 09:34:11
222   QT001           Sometext4   2020-06-29 11:32:23
222   BMX-Jobd        Sometext4   2020-06-29 11:32:23
```

What I have so far, to which I would like to append the above condition as well:

```
SELECT a.some_name,a.some_time, b.desc
FROM Table_A a
LEFT JOIN Table_B b
ON 
(b.j_name IN (a.service_name, 'LL' || SUBSTR(a.some_name, instr(a.some_name, 'AD')+2 ,4)))
or
(b.j_name IN (a.service_name, 'BMX-' || a.some_name))
where a.some_name like 'AB-%' order by log_time desc
```

Answer (score 1):

That seems to be a rather unpleasant problem.

I can't see from your example where there is any logic to the renaming; it appears to be simply a hard-coded list of replacements.

I'd go with something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT some_name,
        CASE some_name
            WHEN 'AB-FBb3' THEN 'QT001'
            -- etc.
            ELSE some_name
        END AS j_name
    FROM Table_A
) AS a
    FULL OUTER JOIN Table_B b ON a.j_name = b.j_name
```

because the `CASE` in the subquery makes it easy to see the re-namings.

Comment: Thanks @Richard Barraclough, it works without the "AS a" by just mentioning the alias as "a" in line 10 of your answer.